# Simplify array slicing with array_slice php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays and I need to display the elements of each array depending on their total number

In total, 2 elements from each array should be displayed, but if one of the arrays has 1 element, then display 3 elements from the other

I did it this way

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

if (count($array2) >= 2) {
    $array1 = array_slice($array1 , 0, 2);
} else if (count($array2 ) === 1) {
    $array1 = array_slice($array1 , 0, 3);
}

if (count($array1) >= 2) {
    $array2 = array_slice($array2 , 0, 2);
} else if (count($array1 ) === 1) {
    $array2 = array_slice($array2 , 0, 3);
}
```

This is a working code, but the question is, is it possible to somehow simplify the counting of the number of elements, and what would it take not 4 lines in the code, but one or two?

Comment: If you have working code, rather than a bug, and you would like opinions on how to improve it, you might find your question is better received on the Code Review Stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would make it simpler:

```
$array1 = array_slice($array1, 0, count($array2) > 1 ? 2 : 3);
$array2 = array_slice($array2, 0, count($array1) > 1 ? 2 : 3);
```

I use the [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Thanks, it works, but there is another problem, when the second array has 0 elements, then all the elements that are in the first array should be displayed. Can this be added to current code without big changes?

Comment: @Hector: You're saying that the first array shouldn't be changed when the second array has no elements. I would do this by surrounding the first line of my answer by: `if (count($array2) > 0) { <place first line here> }`.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer the question ('...less lines').

As of PHP 8 we can use `match` instead of `if`. The code is not that much shorter (5 instead of 7 lines), but it is much more readable than if/elseif/else constructs:

```
$array1 = match ( count($array2) ) {
  0       => $array1,
  1       => array_slice($array1, 0, 3),
  default => array_slice($array1, 0, 2)
};

$array2 = match ( count($array1) ) {
  0       => $array2,
  1       => array_slice($array2, 0, 3),
  default => array_slice($array2, 0, 2)
};
```

Btw, the code in the OP misses in both 'ifs' the case of an empty array. So the line count would increase to 7 for each 'if...endif'.